# How to prove that $(\mathbb Q,+)$ is not isomorphic to $(\mathbb Q^*,\times)$?

Tags: group-theory

> Given that there is the additive group $\mathbb Q$ of rational numbers, and the multiplicative group $\mathbb Q^*$ of non-zero rational numbers, prove that $(\mathbb Q,+)$ is not isomorphic to $(\mathbb Q^*,\times)$.

How many methods can you think of and can you provide a complete solution?

I am a self-learner of maths and feel difficult to offer a rigorous proof, but here are my thoughts:

1. I could try to assume a isomorphism $\theta$ exists between the two groups and prove that $\theta$ cannot exist.
2. I could try to find some property which should preserve under isomorphism but is satisfied only by one of the groups.

However I could not proceed in either direction, could someone please help?

Comment: Do you have a non trivial element of finite order in the first group ? in the second?

Comment: *additive*, not *addictive*...

Comment: @Rescy_: It would be more fun to discuss the isomorphism question when the second group is taken to be consisting of only the *positive rational* numbers (under multiplication).

Comment: the "property" method is almost always the way to go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check for the existence of elements of order $2$.

In the light of this your next question is probably about $(\Bbb Q^*_{>0},\times)$. Then we can resort to the fact that $(\Bbb Q,+)$ is *divisible*.

Comment: Great method! Actually my next question is to prove $(\mathbb R,+)$ being not isomorphic to $(\mathbb R^*,\times)$, which can also be solved using your method. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is true for any field $k$: The equation $x^2=1$ in $k^*$ corresponds to the equation $2x=0$ in $k$; however, they always admit different number of solutions.

Comment: @lhf If $k$ is of char$=2$, then $2x=0$ always hold, but $x^2=1$ admits only one solution.

Comment: you're right, I misread.